# How to fix ArrayList java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 20 out-of-bounds for length 2

Tags: java, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to store the numbers with no pair in my arrayList "colors" but I get this runtime error with my arrayList.
The main gets input for n(size of the array) and input for arItems then it converts the elements in the arItems into integers places them in an int array ar then when it calls the sockMerchant it passes the int n and the int array ar

```
static int sockMerchant(int n, int[] ar) {
    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
    int pairs = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       if (!colors.contains(ar[i])) {
            colors.add(ar[i]);
        } else {
            pairs++;
            colors.remove(ar[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(pairs);
    return pairs;
}
private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // n is the size of the array
    // sample n input: 9
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

    int[] ar = new int[n];

    //sample arItems input: 10 20 20 10 10 30 50 10 20
    String[] arItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int arItem = Integer.parseInt(arItems[i]);
        ar[i] = arItem;
    }

    int result = sockMerchant(n, ar);


    scanner.close();
}
```

***The error I get is:***

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 20 out-of-bounds for length 2
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:517)
    at Solution.sockMerchant(Solution.java:21)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:48)
```

Comment: hey, what do you mean by no pair. add function call as well in code @Janet

Comment: yeah sorry about that I'll edit the code

Comment: @NaveenJain I edited the code and included the function call in my main method :) , a sample input in my array is 10 20 20 10 10 30 50 10 20 I have to find how many pairs there are in the array ( 10 would have 2 pairs, 20 would have 1 pair, 30 and 50 doesn't have a pair, so the number of pairs should be "3" which should be the output of the program).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when you are trying to remove the duplicates from your array `colors`. This is because the `remove()` method of `ArrayList` can either take in an `Object` or an `int` and you are passing in an `int`. This means that you are actually trying to remove a specific index which, in your example is the index 20, but this index doesn't exist in your array.

You can modify your code as such to remove the values correctly based upon index.

```
static int sockMerchant(int n, int[] ar) {
    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
    int pairs = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       if (!colors.contains(ar[i])) {
            colors.add(ar[i]);
        } else {
            pairs++;
            colors.remove(color.indexOf(ar[i]));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(pairs);
    return pairs;
}
```

Comment: oh I forgot remove accepts an index parameter!!! T^T Thank you for pointing this out